# Unreal Engine 5 Small trouble with Blueprint

Tags: openai-api

Good night friends, I'm sitting for the 4th day in a closed dumb situation.

To the point.

Ready to discuss your help financially

I saw on the open spaces interesting for me asset: https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/en-US/produc...

Wanted to make a simple Prop Hunt game, integrating this set of assets in Advanced Locomotion System v4.

From the first minutes due to his inexperience encountered various kinds of problems but gradually found a solution, the last point was the following problem.

We have 3 Character

1. BP_BaseCharacter - Character that stores all scripts, and is used only at the moment of waiting for the connection of players
2. BP_HunterCharacter - A character hunter, looking for other BP_HiderCharacter disguised as Propa.
3. BP_HiderCharacter - Described above, initially the character in the form of a dummy, but using a shot turns into a prop that is prescribed in the database

The problem is the following, if you use only the asset "Prop Hunt" without crutches with ALS, then indeed, everything works well, but I'm not quite satisfied with the movement of the character, the behavior of the camera, and it was decided to integrate into ALS Characters all the necessary for the work of our project Prop Hunt.

All variables, blueprints were merged with ALS, after which everything initially works fine until we run the game

Our BP_HiderCharacter can absolutely become any object, but BP_HunterCharacter cannot destroy BP_HiderCharacter, it seems that BP_HiderCharacter just ignores linetrace

Was expecting a seamless merge of Prop Hunt and ALS assets, and got ambushed, the problem is probably easier to solve than I think, but I lack experience